# Since $A^T B^T = (BA)^T$, what is $A^TC^TB^T$

Tags: matrices

It is well known $A^T B^T = (BA)^T$

So what would be the transpose of $A^TC^TB^T$?

What conditions on C would make it true that $A^TC^TB^T$ = $(BCA)^T$?

Comment: $A^TC^TB^T=(BCA)^T$ always holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the case for two matrices and use induction:
$$
(ABC)^T = C^T(AB)^T = C^TB^TA^T.
$$
You can easily generalize this to arbitrarily large products and see that transposing a product 
inverts the order of the product.

In your particular case you get that:
$$
A^TC^TB^T = (BCA)^T.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no conditions (except for compatibility*, of course):
$$A^T C^T B^T = A^T (C^T B^T) = A^T (BC)^T = ((BC)A)^T = (BCA)^T$$
By associativity of matrix multiplication and by $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

*Matrices $A, B$ are said to be *compatible* if the product $AB$ exists, i.e. if the number of rows of $B$ is equal to the number of columns of $A$.